# Git Push returns "RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated" error

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins Pipeline which is used to pull a git workspace from one remote server and then push to another remote server:

```
stage('Git Pull') {
    steps {
        step([$class: 'WsCleanup'])
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx', url: 'ssh://source-remote-server']]])
    }
}
stage('Git Push') {
    steps {
        sh 'git checkout -b master'
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'yyyy-yyyy-yyyy', passwordVariable: 'GIT_TOKEN')]) {
            sh 'git remote add target_origin https://${GIT_TOKEN}@target-remote-server'
            sh 'git push -u target_origin master'
        }
    }
}
```

However I became following exception when run the pipeline:

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS
>   connection was non-properly terminated.
>   fatal: The remote end hung
>   up unexpectedly
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I did some searching for the solutions and found some but they did not work in my case. What I have tried:

- **set postBuffer**: *git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000*
- **increase the speedLimit**:  *git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 1000*  & *git config --global
  http.lowSpeedTime 600*

What makes me confused here is when I tried another repository with the same process (use the same pipeline to pull and push) and then it worked. These two repositories are hosted in the same source remote server, and same target remote server. The only difference that I can find is the size: the not working one has a size of 3.15 GB and the working one has a size of 3.2 GB, but I dont think this is the reason.

Can anyone help me to figure out which another reasons can cause the above exception and how to fix it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy set up on the target server? I saw similar behavior with nginx timing out and terminating connection on a long lasting request.

Comment: Hi @raspy, unfortunately I can not access the target server, I need to clearify this again. But if it is the case, what could be the solution here?

Comment: My case was nginx logging a 408 response (after which it actually does not send any response but just terminates the connection). This was reported as https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1468 and my workaround included a bigger buffer. YMMV though.